# Multi-label Classification Model Predicts same pattern output for any input

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

Based on what I read online, my task is a multi-label classification as I have ~40k images each with multiple tags and each image can have more than one tag asserted at once. For example, IMAGE_1 -> [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 ... 1] is possible.

I used softmax in final layer and binary_crossentropy as a loss function. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5),  strides=(1,1), activation='relu',  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))

# Create the feature vector
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(17, activation='softmax'))
```

I then **compile**:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

And **train** (notice I only used 1k images here just to speed up the test but I get same results with 40k images):

```
# Save model and stop if overfit
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("model.h5", monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.005, patience=3, verbose=0, mode='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, early_stop]
history = model.fit(data, labels, validation_split=0.33, epochs=20, batch_size=100, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1)
```

Finally, **I predict the output of each input**:

```
CNN_output = model.predict(data)
```

**I get the following output using the following code:**

```
for h in range(len(data)):
    output_file.write("ACTUAL: train_" + str(h) + ": " + "\n" + str(labels[h]) + "\n")
    output_file.write("PREDICTION: train_" + str(h) + ": " + "\n" + str(CNN_output[h]) + "\n")
```

[Actual Vs Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Fgm.png)

As can be seen the pattern in the predictions is the same as [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0...] for any input, and I have no idea why this is!

Here is what each epoch looks like:
[Accuracy Vs Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACOX3.png)

It can be seen that validation accuracy remains constant which is a result of the above mentioned problem I assume.
Also the F_score is very low compared to accuracy which also seems to be due to the above mentioned problem.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Regards,
Lior

Comment: I'm not sure I understand image classification where images can belong to multiple classes simultaneously(?), so I might be way off, but are your training classes balanced? If you have a dominant class represented in your training data, for example, 80% of your images are cats, the model will always predict cat, with an accuracy of 80%. Again, sorry if I have completely misunderstood.

Comment: I think you didn't quite get my question so an example I can give that will explain what I mean is lets say you have two classes "DAY" and "NIGHT". For each you can have labels like sunny, cloudy, clear, dark, etc.
Now to describe the class "DAY" you can use the labels sunny and clear at same time right?

Comment: Hello Lior, I have the exact same result after training my network on a multi label dataset. Did you find any solution or ideas ?
I think what @StarkJA raised is not that irrelevant, because my dataset is really unbalanced and the classes that are more represented tend to have greater scores.

Comment: Hey A. Piro, I decided to break down my multi label into individual labels, so instead of training on [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 ... 1], I now train on just [first index] for each input (then second index, and so on) so each index will get a different model and "**binary_crossentropy**" can be used on the output layer. Also adding class weights for each index in the fit function seemed to make the skewed data train better. For example, fit(...., class_weight={0:0.1,1:0.9}) can be used if the index being tested contains 9 times more 0's than 1's (basically more occurrence means assigning lower probability)